# Drive API returns 'file Id: undefined'

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to node.js but still want to try my best to get this code block running. Everything seems to work correctly and my folders in fact get created but i am getting 'file Id:  undefined' in the console each time.

I looked at at a few other posts suggesting a .then command but I am not able to run it successfully. Any advice/help would be super appreciated!

```
  let drive = google.drive("v3");
  let folderId = '1hlkFcK0zFa6Qqs8pUwTRm3gxxx';
  let fileMetadata = {
  'name': [`${newDataArray}`],
  'parents': [folderId],
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
  "resource": {}
  };
    drive.files.create({
    auth: cl,
    resource: fileMetadata,
    fields: 'id'  
    }, function (err, file) {
    if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
    } else {
    console.log('File Id: ', file.id);

    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!!! it's file.data.id and not file.id in console.log

```
let drive = google.drive("v3");
  let folderId = '1hlkFcK0zFa6Qqs8pUwTRm3xxx';
  let fileMetadata = {
  'name': [`${newDataArray}`],
  'parents': [folderId],
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
  'response': 'file.id'
  };
    drive.files.create({
    auth: cl,
    resource: fileMetadata,
    fields:'id'  
    }, 
    function (err, file) {
    if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
    } else {
    // console.log('New Folder: https://drive.google.com/corp/drive/folders/' + file.data.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `fields` property. If you console log the err object you should see this explained.

Set fields to one of `files(id)` or `*` or simply omit it altogether.